# What does String mean in context of counting theory?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

What does "String" mean in context of counting theory ? For example :

> There are 8 *binary* strings of length 3 .

What does binary and length signify here ?

**Edit** : I want to specifically why it is called a String ?

Comment: It says there are $8$ three-letter "words" using the alphabet $\{0,1\}$. Here are a few: $000$, $001$, $010$, $011$, $100$, three more to go.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I edited the question slightly . I want to know why it is called String ?

Comment: For variety. Like a string of beads. "Sequence" is common too, kinda boring. "Word" is freqently used also.  All of these terms convey the notion that order is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

binary string means $\textit{a sequence of 0's and 1's}$ and the length defines the number of elements in the sequence.

Like $10011$ is a binary string of length $5$, $110011100$ is a binary string of length $9$ etc.